# Is there a decent workaround to saving checkpoints in local drive when using TPU in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

A follow up to this question:

[How to save a Tensorflow Checkpoint file from Google Colaboratory in when using TPU mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003208/how-to-save-a-tensorflow-checkpoint-file-from-google-colaboratory-in-when-using)

Where the official way of saving a checkpoint when using a Tensorflow TPU is to use the Google Cloud Service.

I am working if there is a workaround to this for those who do not wish to use GCS. Perhaps for each variable, do a .eval(), save the variable. And then set the save variable to the 'init' value for each variable.

A major issue I foresee though is saving and loading the parameters for the optimizers.

For Keras, the weights do seem to be saved from TPU to local

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shakespeare_with_tpu_and_keras.ipynb

> INFO:tensorflow:Copying TPU weights to the CPU

So I imagine that there's a general workaround too, without using keras.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [THIS CODE from Keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bde19b79b3d5e0d4be679f8144acb7f06b1c83ee/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/keras_support.py#L2040-L2072)

If I understood correctly weights are not saved drectly from TPU, instead weights are synced to CPU and the saved to colab storage.

**EDIT**

Also see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056640/1433554).

Answer (score -1):

I just found the below solution after seeing this thread, so I wanted to add this option in. From the tensorflow documentation, there is an `option` field that you can use in save/load/restore functions in keras as well as `tf.train.Checkpoint` and the save method of `tf.train.CheckpointManager` which allow you to pass in an experimental localhost syncing strategy.

Copying their code example:

```py
model = get_model()

# Saving the model to a path on localhost.
saved_model_path = '/tmp/tf_save'
save_options = tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(experimental_io_device='/job:localhost')
model.save(saved_model_path, options=save_options)

# Loading the model from a path on localhost.
another_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with another_strategy.scope():
  load_options = tf.saved_model.LoadOptions(experimental_io_device='/job:localhost')
  loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path, options=load_options)
```

Documentation Sources:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load#savingloading_from_a_local_device
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore